# How to write a custom controller for sitecore SXA search result in sitecore 9.0.1?

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I want to create a customized search result rendering in order to achieve that I have to create a custom search result component. For creating custom search result component I have created a controller, model class and repository. while overriding the repository GetModel() method. I m getting an error no suitable method found to override.
[image]

IRepository interface

[image]

Can anyone please suggest where I m going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can you also share SearchResultCustomComponentModel so that it will me more clear to respond to you issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetModel()` method is a virtual method of SXA `AbstractRepository`. Most of SXA repositories inherits from it, that is why we are overriding that method in a lot of places (as you probably noticed). What you need to do is to implement that method (as it comes from your interface) rather than override.

The same with `FillBaseProperties()` method. That is a virtual method of SXA base `ModelRepository`. The same, most of our repositories are using that base class so that we are overriding and using that method in `GetModel()`.